# how can i save div content to php code widout showing the html tag?

Tags: php, html

My script creats a div id output shown as a url text, this is the html tag output:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

i want following php code to be equal only to the url text and not the html tag.
so how can i get this to work?

```
<? $value = '<div id="result"></div>'; ?>
```

because my final result needs to be:

```
<a href="<? echo $value; ?>">link</a>
```

Comment: Data inside `<div id="result"></div>` came from where? DB or static?

Comment: So you are setting the value of `<div id="result">` and you want to use that value to set the `href` of `link` ? Is this being set via javascript?

Comment: If I understand what you want correctly (and I'm not sure if I am or not), then it's not possible. HREF attribute should contain a hypertext link, for example a URI or bookmarks, but not entire DOM trees.

Comment: the <div id="result"></div> comes from javascript (its a shrot url from goo.gl)

Comment: @DigiNetEvents : if you are getting that result from `JS` then why not put that into `ahref` also.

Comment: @DigiNetEvents : check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` in you `a` tag.

```
 <a href="<? echo $value; ?>" id='custom-link'>link</a>
```

Then add one more line to your Js. You will not need to do that in `php`

```
if (response.id != null) {
    str = "";
    str += response.id;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
    document.getElementById("custom-link").href = str;

}
```